# C++ separate class file problems

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I'm working on another school project in which I'm supposed to use multiple files for my class... that is, `whatever.h` and `whatever.cpp`. I totally get how to use them, but for some reason, when I start building code with them, I get a boatload of errors. I'll post the code from my `Person.h` and `Person.cpp` and then the errors I get.

`Person.h`:

```
#pragma once
class Person
{
public:
    Person();
    ~Person();
    void setGender(string Gen);
    string getGender();
private:
    int Age;
    string Gender;
    int AnnualIncome;


};
```

`Person.cpp`:

```
#include "Person.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>     //I'll be using this later.
#include <fstream>    //I'll be using this later.

using namespace std;

Person::Person()
{

}


Person::~Person()
{
}

void Person::setGender(string Gen)
{
    Gender = Gen;
}

string Person::getGender()
{

    return string(Gender);
}
```

The errors I'm getting are as follows:

```
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'string'   Marketing Software  c:\users\danny\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\marketing software\person.h    7   Build

Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'string'   Marketing Software  c:\users\danny\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\marketing software\person.h    7   Build

Error   C3646   'getGender': unknown override specifier Marketing Software  c:\users\danny\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\marketing software\person.h    8   Build

Error   C2059   syntax error: '('   Marketing Software  c:\users\danny\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\marketing software\person.h    8   Build

Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   Marketing Software  c:\users\danny\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\marketing software\person.h    8   Build

Error   C3646   'getGender': unknown override specifier Marketing Software  c:\users\danny\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\marketing software\person.h    8   Build

Error   C2059   syntax error: '('   Marketing Software  c:\users\danny\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\marketing software\person.h    8   Build

Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   Marketing Software  c:\users\danny\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\marketing software\person.h    8   Build

Error   C3646   'Gender': unknown override specifier    Marketing Software  c:\users\danny\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\marketing software\person.h    11  Build

Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Marketing Software  c:\users\danny\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\marketing software\person.h    11  Build

Error   C3646   'Gender': unknown override specifier    Marketing Software  c:\users\danny\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\marketing software\person.h    11  Build

Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Marketing Software  c:\users\danny\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\marketing software\person.h    11  Build

Error   C2511   'void Person::setGender(std::string)': overloaded member function not found in 'Person' Marketing Software  c:\users\danny\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\marketing software\person.cpp  19  Build

Error   C2065   'Gender': undeclared identifier Marketing Software  c:\users\danny\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\marketing software\person.cpp  20  Build

Error   C2039   'getGender': is not a member of 'Person'    Marketing Software  c:\users\danny\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\marketing software\person.cpp  23  Build

Error   C2065   'Gender': undeclared identifier Marketing Software  c:\users\danny\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\marketing software\person.cpp  26  Build

Error   C2660   'Person::setGender': function does not take 1 arguments Marketing Software  c:\users\danny\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\marketing software\source.cpp  32  Build

Error   C2039   'getGender': is not a member of 'Person'    Marketing Software  c:\users\danny\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\marketing software\source.cpp  33  Build
```

I'm not sure what to do because I've tried redoing this several times, and I have looked up those specific errors, and I can't figure out what is wrong with my program.

Comment: Add `#include <string>` and other std includes and `using namespace std` to the header files

Comment: You forgot to include `<string>` in your header and qualify your usages with `std::`. Always fix the first error first, because the others often cascade from it.

Comment: @Alex: No, do not add `using namespace std` to the header. That's a terrible practice!

Comment: @AlexStepanov You should almost never have `using namespace std;` in a header file.

Comment: @Cameron  Yes I know, however I doesn't matter in the context of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you should do two things:

1. Include required headers directly into your own header files, whenever possible, to make it work stand-alone and not depend on include order. `string` is not defined unless you `#include <string>`.
2. Use fully-qualified names for types in header files: `string` does not exist in the global namespace, as `std::string` resides in the namespace `std`, so you should refer to it via `std::string`.

Finally, it's often a good idea to include official library headers before user-defined headers, so you should include `string` and `vector` before `Person.h` in your cpp file.

These changes mean for your particular case that year header becomes:

Person.h

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

class Person
{
public:
    Person();
    ~Person();
    void setGender(std::string Gen);
    std::string getGender();
private:
    int Age;
    std::string Gender;
    int AnnualIncome;
};
```

And your cpp file becomes:

Person.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>     //I'll be using this later.
#include <fstream>    //I'll be using this later.
#include "Person.h"

using namespace std;

Person::Person()
{

}


Person::~Person()
{
}

void Person::setGender(string Gen)
{
    Gender = Gen;
}

string Person::getGender()
{
    return Gender;
}
```

Finally, a minor remark: it's usually not a good idea to use `using namespace std` as this imports everything and it's often better to select just what you need, such as `using std::string;`, `using std::vector;`, etc.

Comment: I agree with everything you said, except the bit about the order of includes. It is advantageous to include your own header file before any other headers. That way, the person.cpp file ensures that person.h is idempotent, i.e. it compiles on its own without any errors and has no other header dependencies other than the ones it includes itself.

Comment: I followed your advice and changed my code to what you posted. Unfortunately, that didn't solve all of the errors. I'm down to four, but I can't figure out how to fix them.

 Error C2597 illegal reference to non-static member   person.cpp 21
 
        Error C2061 syntax error: identifier 'string'   person.h 10
 
        Error C2061 syntax error: identifier 'string'   person.h 10
 
        Error C2511 'void Person::setGender(std::string)': overloaded member function not found in 'Person'   person.cpp 20

Comment: @Danny I missed one `string` to `std::string` in the header in `setGender`. Try it now, and if you still get errors maybe post the first.

Comment: I tried to format my comment above in editing it... it didn't work, but they are there now. I did try it, and it took it down from 6 errors.

Comment: @Danny The code currently in my answer compiles for me without errors.

Comment: Ok, you are right... I accidentally forgot to refresh the error list. My compiler has a bug where I have to manually refresh the error list (it is supposed to do it automatically). Thanks!